# Time difference compare to presence like Twitter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter, time

Is there a gem or another easy way to get time difference compare to present time like Twitter?

Of course I can write it myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: what are you trying to ask , you can always subtract the time from the current time , just keep in mind if you are doing it at the server , keep in mind doing it with correct time zone , or you can always do it at front end.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked more accurately. I want to get not simple difference, but "twitter like" difference. like "about 2 hours".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rails, you could do

```
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now @user.created_at
#=> "15 days"
```

or

```
time_ago_in_words @post.created_at
#=> "about 13 hours"
```